# Unable to create cluster in Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, cluster, alwayson

I am trying to create a cluster in between two networks/gateway and validation is perfectly passing and after that i am getting error as

An error occurred while creating the cluster and the nodes will be cleaned up. Please wait...
where as i see in event id (During node cleanup, the local user account that is managed by the cluster was not deleted. The error code was '2221'. Open Local Users and Groups (lusrmgr.msc) to delete the account.) Where as i am able to configure cluster on the same server in local networks